# Setting focus for new tab on an tab browser

Tags: javascript, tabs, focus

I use the code below to open a new browser.

```
    var winHndle = window.open(url,'myWindow');
    winHndle.focus();
```

I don't mind if user settings come into play and it opens in a new window or tab.

**My issue is I want the focus to change if the window/tab already exists. I can see the handle works fine - it refreshes, but focus doesn't change to that tab.**

I keep seeing posts saying use `focus()`, but it just doesn't work.

Without mucking around with user settings only IE and safari seem to open in a new window with this code. I just download and installed most recent versions of firefox, opera, safari and chrome - already had IE 8. So for most browsers my focus code is useless :-(

FYI...I use "myWindow" so the next time I open the window it opens/refreshes the same instance if it's still there.

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">Click here to open in new window/tab</a>
```

I use that all the time and it works. It always focuses on the new window opened.

I hope this helps you.